# Login form is not rendered from aspx file which lives in delphi dll

Tags: asp.net, forms, delphi, authentication, dll

I am trying to implement forms authentication for our web application. All the code runs off a DLL written in delphi. I created an aspx file in my DLL to render the login form and I have successfully set up my IIS to redirect users to the aspx login page when they have not been authenticated.

Although the users are successfully redirected, the login form is not rendered on the browser.
Here is my FormsLogin.aspx code:

```
<%@ Page language="c#" Codebehind="FormsLogin.pas" AutoEventWireup="false"         Inherits="FormsLogin.TFormsLogin" %>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>

  <body>
     <form runat="server">
     Password&nbsp;
      <ASP:TextBox id="TextBox1" runat="server"/></form>
  </body>
    </html>
```

And here is the FormsLogin.pas code:

```
unit FormsLogin;

interface

uses
  System.Collections, System.ComponentModel,
  System.Data, System.Drawing, System.Web, System.Web.SessionState,
  System.Web.UI, System.Web.UI.WebControls, System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

type
  TFormsLogin = class(System.Web.UI.Page)
  {$REGION 'Designer Managed Code'}
  strict private
    procedure InitializeComponent;
  {$ENDREGION}
  strict private
    procedure Page_Load(sender: System.Object; e: System.EventArgs);
  strict protected
    TextBox1: System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox;
    procedure OnInit(e: EventArgs); override;
  private
    { Private Declarations }
  public
    { Public Declarations }
  end;

implementation

{$REGION 'Designer Managed Code'}
/// <summary>
/// Required method for Designer support -- do not modify
/// the contents of this method with the code editor.
/// </summary>
procedure TFormsLogin.InitializeComponent;
begin
  Include(Self.Load, Self.Page_Load);
end;
{$ENDREGION}

procedure TFormsLogin.Page_Load(sender: System.Object; e: System.EventArgs);
begin
  // TODO: Put user code to initialize the page here
 { response.Write('<html><head><title>Test</title></head>'
      +  '<body><form runat="server">'
      + 'Username&nbsp;'
      + '<input id="TextBox1" runat="server"/></form>'
      + '</body></html>');                }
end;

procedure TFormsLogin.OnInit(e: EventArgs);
begin
  //
  // Required for Designer support
  //
  InitializeComponent;
  inherited OnInit(e);
end;

end.
```

If I add HTML code in the Page_Load procedure it does get renderred but I would very much like to avoid going down that path.

I have added the following verb in my web.cofig file:

```
<add name="FormLogin.aspx_*" path="FormsLogin.aspx" verb="*" type="FormsLogin.TFormsLogin, dll_name" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Execute" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0" />
```

I would appreciate any help you could give me.

Thanks.

Comment: What is this? Delphi.net?

Comment: Yes! Running the web site on IIS 7.5.